# Quick access to multiple values

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, struct

Not a Unity question per se, but it helps me illustrate this problem.

Properties can't return multiple values. However, in Unity Vector3.up, shorthand for Vector3(0, 1, 0) **seems** to do so (to me, anyway). For example, typing Debug.Log(Vector3.up) prints out the previously mentioned three values. I'm not sure what exactly is happening that gives access to those three values in such a direct way.

I've tried to get as much information about classes and structs as is possible for my level of knowledge, but I haven't been able to figure this out. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Just a guess, i don't know that class and the Unity docs are ... special. My guess: what you see is the return value of `Vector3.ToString()` method. E.g. `public string ToString() { return x+y+z;}` (pseudo code, could not find it, dont want to install it ;) )

Comment: It is not possible to return more then one value. You will always have a signature like `public bool IsItSomething()`, that would return a `bool`. You could use [out parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) or return a wrapper class containing all values needed or use [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2?view=net-5.0) in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

no need to read the docs if you can have the [Source Code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Math/Vector3.cs#L453) ;)

=>  [`Vector3.up`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Runtime/Export/Math/Vector3.cs#L389) indeed just is a shorthand and returns

> ```
> public static readonly Vector3.up = new Vector3(0F, 1F, 0F);
> ```

and the [`Vector3.ToString`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Runtime/Export/Math/Vector3.cs#L453) internally does

> ```
> public override string ToString()
> {
>     return ToString(null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
> }
>
> public string ToString(string format)
> {
>     return ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
> }
>
> public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
> {
>     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(format))
>         format = "F1";
>     return UnityString.Format("({0},{1}, {2})", x.ToString(format, formatProvider), y.ToString(format,formatProvider), z.ToString(format, formatProvider));
> }
> ```

Where finally the [`UnityString.Format`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Modules/SharedInternals/UnityString.cs#L20) basically does what one expects

> ```
> public static string Format(string fmt, params object[] args)
> {
>     return String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, fmt, args);
> }
> ```

There is no deeper magic involved here ;)